# Mac OS X Lion - Outlook 2011 Sync with iPhone

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sync, iphone, microsoft-outlook-2011

I just had to reinstall Outlook 2011 and im having problems to sync my contacts and calendar with my iphone.

When i open the Sync Services panel on Outlook it doesnt show nothing, its blank, just as the image below.

My Outlook and mac os X Lion are updated to the last versions. I've tried to use iSync from the web but it doesnt install, just open, and doesnt recognize my iphone.

Any idea how can i synchronize them? I used to have Mountain Lion but i downgraded to Lion to sync, i remember it did but now i do not remember how i did.... Any ideas? Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under outlook preferences / sync services (at the bottom) do you have the contacts and calendar switched on there?

Comment: When i click Sync Services it is all blank, just as showed in the image

Comment: In finder, under the Go menu - select Go to folder and type 

~/Library/Preferences and press enter.

Then find and delete this file (without brackets):

(com.microsoft.Outlook.SyncServicesPreferences.plist)

Exit and go to outlook sync services again in outlook preferences.